# Is is possible to always display scrollbars in an MGWT ScrollPanel?

Tags: gwt, mgwt

Some of the stakeholders on my project expressed doubt in easily recognizing hidden vertical content to scroll to in an MGWT [ScrollPanel](http://docs.mgwt.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/latest/index.html?com/googlecode/mgwt/ui/client/widget/ScrollPanel.html) (without taking a swipe at it). As an attempt to address the concern I'd like to always show the pretty semi-transparent vertical scrollbar as both a hint of more content to scroll to and an indication of the ratio between the amount of displayed vs. all content in the panel.

Is it possible to keep the panel's scrollbars permanently displayed? At first I thought the `setShowScrollBarY(boolean)` would do the trick but quickly proved myself wrong.

P.S.: Shouldn't there be an `m-gwt` StackOverflow tag by now? AFAIKT MGWT has gained sufficient traction to have an MGWT-specific stream of questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had the same issues with clients that suggested that showing scrollbars would be a good idea. If you cut your content right its easy to see for the user that there is more content..

Anyhow I just added a setHideScrollBar(boolean) to the trunk. Download it from ( https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=snapshots&g=com.googlecode.mgwt&a=mgwt&e=jar&v=LATEST) and give it a try. Maybe we should also think of an option to flash the scrollbars once to indicate that there is more content.

By the way I would be supporting an mgwt specific tags as I do with the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/group/mgwt

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot for adding this. Upon testing in FF13 noticed no issues when content height exceeds panel height. When content fits, however, the vertical bar is still visible but becomes a black dot at the panel's bottom-right (should probably go away completely). Haven't tried neither other browsers nor the horizontal bar.

Comment: Thank you for the `mgwt` tag as well. Added to my Google Reader.